# How do I put the 3 selection before the random game using tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

I have two message box: 1 is the game, another one is welcome message box. Wish to put the selection of level before the random game but I have no idea on it. May anyone assist me in this issue? Thank you.

coding skills to make this issue resolve

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to display the welcome message and level selection at the start of the game.

#### Messages and windows before starting the game.

For simple cases, you can use [messageboxes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html).

For more complex interfaces, you can use a [toplevel](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html) widget.

The root window can be hidden so that the user can perform some actions in separate windows before starting the game: read the rules, choose a username or level, etc.
For this, we will define functions that will create and display these windows.

We also need to create functions that handle user selections. Depending on the user's choice, we can call these functions to show the next window or create a game screen.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import Message


def welcome_message(parent):
    """Create and show messagebox."""
    msg = Message(master=parent, title="Welcome",
                  message="Here is some description.\nDo you want to start the game?",
                  icon="question", type="yesno")
    res = msg.show()
    if res == "yes":
        levels(parent) # second window
    else:
        parent.destroy() # same as root.destroy()
    
def levels(parent):
    """Create and show Toplevel."""
    top = tk.Toplevel(parent, name="top_levels")
    top.title("Select Level")
    # set the same function or different functions for the buttons
    level_button1 = tk.Button(top, text="Easy", command=lambda: create_game("Easy"))
    level_button1.pack()
    level_button2 = tk.Button(top, text="Medium", command=lambda: create_game("Medium"))
    level_button2.pack()
    level_button3 = tk.Button(top, text="Hard", command=lambda: create_game("Hard"))
    level_button3.pack()
    # if the user closed the window
    top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", parent.destroy) # root.destroy()


def create_game(level):
    """Creating a game depending on the user's choice."""
    # destroy the top level window
    top_level = root.nametowidget("top_levels") # get a widget by its unique name
    top_level.destroy()
    # create a game screen
    game_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow")
    game_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    level_label = tk.Label(game_frame, text=f"Level: {level}", bg="lightblue")
    level_label.pack()
    root.deiconify() # show root

    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")
root.title("App")

root.withdraw() # hide root

welcome_message(root) # first window

root.mainloop()
```

#### Messages and level selection in one game window.

One of the possible options is to pack the game into one frame. This frame will be used to change the labels and buttons on the game screen.

First, we create a text message. If the user selects "yes", we recreate the content of the frame with the new buttons (levels). And so on.

Again, we need to create functions to handle the user's selection.

```py
import tkinter as tk


def clear(parent):
    # clear main frame
    for i in parent.winfo_children():
        i.destroy()

        
def welcome_message(parent):
    label = tk.Label(parent, text="Here is some description.\nDo you want to start the game?")
    label.pack()
    button1 = tk.Button(parent, text="Yes", command=lambda: levels(parent))
    button1.pack()
    button2 = tk.Button(parent, text="No", command=root.destroy)
    button2.pack()


def levels(parent):
    clear(parent)
    label = tk.Label(parent, text="Select Level")
    label.pack()
    # set the same function or different functions for the buttons
    level_button1 = tk.Button(parent, text="Easy", command=lambda: start_game("Easy", parent))
    level_button1.pack()
    level_button2 = tk.Button(parent, text="Medium", command=lambda: start_game("Medium", parent))
    level_button2.pack()
    level_button3 = tk.Button(parent, text="Hard", command=lambda: start_game("Hard", parent))
    level_button3.pack()

    
def start_game(level, parent):
    """Creating a game depending on the user's choice."""
    clear(parent)
    # create a game screen
    game_frame = tk.Frame(parent, bg="yellow")
    game_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    level_label = tk.Label(game_frame, text=f"Level: {level}", bg="lightblue")
    level_label.pack()

    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x150")
root.title("App")

root_label = tk.Label(root, text="Game")
root_label.pack()
main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# create frame content
welcome_message(main_frame)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to put my game but I was unable to connect it, may I have your help? Here is my game:

Comment: Wish to set the easy level = 30 seconds, medium is 45 and hard is 60 seconds. Here is my game:

import tkinter
import random
 
# list of possible colour.
colours = ['Red','Blue','Green','Pink','Black',
           'Yellow','Orange','White','Purple','Brown']
score = 0
 
# the game time left, initially 30 seconds.
timeleft = 30
 
# function that will start the game.
def startGame(event):
     
    if timeleft == 30:
      
        # start the countdown timer.
        countdown()

Comment: Write code that people can copy and run for testing. Or at least a minimal example from which the structure of your program will be clear; what you want to connect with what. Open a new question with the code you have. Describe exactly what your program is supposed to do and what difficulties or errors you are encountering.